# screen_name restrictions for Google Analytics App+Web property

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

We are using Google's "[App+Web](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/app-web)" property tracking for our mobile & web apps. For event names, there are [restrictions](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase%20event%20name%20limit&oq=firebase%20event%20name%20limit&ie=UTF-8):

> Event names can be up to 40 characters long, may only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores ("_"), and must start with an alphabetic character.

So all our event names are like `content_play_click` or `view_privacy_policy` etc., for example:

```js
gtag('event', 'view_privacy_policy', data || {});
```

But is there any similar restriction on `screen_name` for [`screen_view`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/app-web/screen-view) using `gtag`?

For example:

```js
gtag('event', 'screen_view', {
    'screen_name': 'Home Page'
});
```

Because it's not showing properly in Google Analytics. It's showing `(other)` or `(not set)`:

[image]

I tried to search a lot about this but couldn't find anything solid. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you need to set app name in gtag event:

```js
gtag('event', 'screen_view', {
    'screen_name': 'Home Page'
   'app_name': 'Your app name'
});
```

Comment: Well, I have already tried this before but this was not showing up in the real time traffic.

Comment: screen_view it is app event for implementation this event you need to send it with firebase analytics from your app

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for this the information is here : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#parameters_1

Basically params names should be less than 40chars and params values should be less than 100 chars